# How to keep playing sound files before the check button clicks in python?

Tags: python

I am now trying to make a program of dictating speech in python.
I have made Entry to input dictation of speech, answer_check button, reset button using tkinter,
and defined function of initial(), answer_check(), Reset().
It works well without playing sound of speech, which is mp3 file of a sentence.
I have inserted playsound('*.mp3') in the middle of each function,which is initial() and Reset().
Actually I wanted while playing sound file after GUI working, dictation going on, and clicking the check button after finishing dictation, then stopping playing sound simultaneously showing the answer.
But this has not occurred. The order was played sound, Entry GUI appeared, entered dictation, checked the answer. I have recognized the reason why. GUI appears after finishing its function, but playing sound appears during doing function.Is this understanding right?
So I defined a new function of playing sound MyPlaySound():
I am now asking at this point how to stop playing sound file when the condition satisfied(check or reset button clicked). Here is the code showing only functions I made, but it has gone into infinite loop.
Please let me know how to make these functions, especially the function of MyPlaySound(), there are some error in that function because I am not sure the syntax in it.
I know this is so easy to experts. I spent whole day but I am not sure how many days to spend to solve this without helping you expert. Thanks in advance.
'''

## Functions

```
def initial():
global shuffled_words, play_num, play_num_row, given_words, ans, u_num_list
label1.configure(text=shuffled_words[play_num_row])
MyPlaySound()

def ans_check():
global shuffled_words, play_num, play_num_row, given_words, ans, u_num_list
ans = str()
ans = ' '.join(given_words[play_num_row])
user_input = e1.get()
if user_input == ans:
    msgbox.showinfo("Success", "Yeop, this is right")
    label2.configure(text=given_words[play_num_row])
else:
    msgbox.showinfo("Error", "Nop, this is not right")
    e1.delete(0, END)
    label2.configure(text=given_words[play_num_row])


def Reset():
global shuffled_words, play_num, play_num_row, given_words, ans, u_num_list
play_num_row = random.randint(0, len(given_words)-1)
play_num = u_num_list[play_num_row]
label1.configure(text=shuffled_words[play_num_row])
label2.config(text="")
e1.delete(0, END)
MyPlaySound()


def MyPlaySound():
global shuffled_words, play_num, play_num_row, given_words, ans, u_num_list
i = 0
while True:
    playsound(str(play_num)+'.mp3')
    i = i + 1
    if ans_check() == True:
        break
    elif Reset() == True:
        break
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't got what you asking but still to do multiple task simultaneously use threading.

```
import threading
def func():
    #function/task to be threaded

thread1=threading.Thread(target=func)
thread1.start()

#To stop the thread
thread1.join()
```

Comment: Thanks. I got a little bit of understanding thread concept as you informed to me. After applying it to program, it works. But thread1.join() does not work to stop the thread. However  I am going to try to understand it more and apply to my program. I really appreciate and thank for your giving information to me. I hope good luck to you.